# Appending a fragment to a node is not working in ie 7 but working in ie8

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to append some `ul` and `li` elements directly into the DOM. I am using a fragment and appending the child nodes to the fragment and at last appending the fragment to the node.

```
function updateTree(objArray,leafClass){

    var currentElement = document.getElementById(currentNodeId);
    currentElement.setAttribute("class",'jstree-open jstree-unchecked');
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var ulElement = document.createElement('ul');
    var i = objArray.length;
    //LoopStart
    for (var i = 0, j = objArray.length ; i < j; i++ ){
    //while(i--){
    var liElement = document.createElement('li');

    liElement.setAttribute("id", objArray[i].attr.id);
    liElement.setAttribute("class",'jstree-closed jstree-unchecked '+leafClass+'');
    liElement.innerHTML = "<ins class=\"jstree-icon\">&nbsp;</ins><a href=\"#\" class=\"\"><ins class=\"jstree-checkbox\">&nbsp;</ins><ins class=\"jstree-icon\">&nbsp;</ins>" + objArray[i].data + "</a> ";

    if(currentElement.getAttribute("class").indexOf('leaf') > 0){
        ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
        fragment.appendChild(ulElement);
        //$(currentElement.childNodes[1]).removeClass('jstree-laoding');
        //console.log("update Tree inside if: " + objArray[i].data);
        return "OK";
    }

    ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
    fragment.appendChild(ulElement);
    //console.log("update Tree for : " + objArray[i].data);
    //}
    }
    //LoopEnd
    currentElement.appendChild(fragment.cloneNode(true));
    currentElement.childNodes[1].setAttribute("class","");
    //console.log("update Tree end: ");
    ////console.log("time"+timer.getDiff());
    //$(currentElement.childNodes[1]).removeClass('jstree-laoding');
    return "OK";
  }
```

The code is working fine in IE8 and Firefox, but in IE7, I cannot see the elements that I am appending; the page is blank.

Comment: couldnt find the use of `ulElement.appendChild(liElement); fragment.appendChild(ulElement);` can u brief why u have used it twice once inside then out of if too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure though i guess the issue is with your

```
if(currentElement.getAttribute("class").indexOf('leaf') > 0){
        ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
        fragment.appendChild(ulElement);
        //$(currentElement.childNodes[1]).removeClass('jstree-laoding');
        //console.log("update Tree inside if: " + objArray[i].data);
        return "OK";
    }
```

i tried a simple code

```
<html><head><script>
function abc(){
alert(document.getElementById("a1").getAttribute("class"));
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="abc();">

<div id="a1" class="ac"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

it alerts
ff - > ac
ie8 -> null
ie7 -> null

**solution** : instead of using getAttribute use className

- document.getElementById("a1").getAttribute("class") - > wrong
  implementation
- ***document.getElementById("a1").className -> correct implementation***

and the use of the `if` block is quite abrupt will like to you to check it according to your use.